# get values from data frame to another

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm new to R programming and just started to learn it, and i need you to help me with this issue please.

I have 2 data frames :

```
the first(df1):

    V1 V2
    A  A 
    A  B 
    A  C 
    B  A 
    B  B 
    B  C 

etc
```

the second(df2) :

```
V1  Va   Vb
A   12   23
B   15   53
C   321  543
D   54   325
etc..
```

Use this code to generate the sample data.

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  V1 = rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 3L),
  V2 = rep.int(LETTERS[1:3], 2L)
)
dfr2 <- data.frame(
  Va = c(12, 15, 312, 54),
  Vb = c(23, 53, 543, 325)
)
```

I need to take the Va and Vb from df2 and place them in df1 based on V1 and V2 of df1.

so I want this output:

df3:

```
V1   V2  Va1  Vb1 Va2 Vb2
A    A   12    23  12  23
A    B   12    23  15  23
A    C   12    23  321 543
B    A   15    23  12   23
B    B   15    23  15   23
B    C   15    23  321  543
```

hope that this can be done in R without a dozenz of for loops :S.

Comment: See also: [Subsetting a data frame based on contents of another data frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452205/subsetting-a-data-frame-based-on-contents-of-another-data-frame)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the power of match() for this, provided the names in df1$V1 are unique :

```
#some data
df1 <- data.frame(
  V1 = rep(c("A","B"),each=3),
  V2 = rep(LETTERS[1:3],2)  
)
df2 <- data.frame(V1=LETTERS[1:3],Va=1:3,Vb=3:1)

out <- cbind(df1,
  df2[match(df1$V1,df2$V1),-1],
  df2[match(df1$V2,df2$V1),-1]
)
names(out)[3:6] <- c("Va1","Vb1","Va2","Vb2")
rownames(out) <- 1:nrow(out)
```

Gives

```
> out
    V1 V2 Va1 Vb1 Va2 Vb2
1    A  A   1   3   1   3
2    A  B   1   3   2   2
3    A  C   1   3   3   1
4    B  A   2   2   1   3
5    B  B   2   2   2   2
6    B  C   2   2   3   1
```

You'll have to rename the columns manually, as you would get multiple columns with the same name. Although it's technically possible in a dataframe, it can cause trouble later on. You can automatize this using something along the lines of:

```
names(out) <- 
    c("V1","V2",
      sapply(names(df2)[2:3],paste,1:2,sep="")
    )
```

---

EDIT : for big dataframes, conversion to matrices makes another huge difference. One has to pay attention to the intrinsic changes in type for the different variables. The speedup is due to the fact that cbind and merge take a whole lot of time figuring out the correct types for each variable.

With following data and functions :

```
n <- 1e5
df1 <- data.frame(V1 = rep(LETTERS,each=n),V2 = rep(LETTERS,n),
        stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(V1=LETTERS,Va=1:26,Vb=26:1,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

fast_JM <- function(df1,df2){
  out <- cbind(
    as.matrix(df2[,-1])[match(df1$V1,df2$V1),],
    as.matrix(df2[,-1])[match(df1$V2,df2$V1),]
  )
  out <- as.data.frame(out)
  names(out) <- sapply(names(df2)[2:3],paste,1:2,sep="")
  out$V1 <- df1$V1
  out$V2 <- df1$V2
  out
}

slow_JM <- function(df1,df2){
  out <- cbind(df1,
    df2[match(df1$V1,df2$V1),-1],
    df2[match(df1$V2,df2$V1),-1]
  )
  names(out)[3:6] <- c("Va1","Vb1","Va2","Vb2")
  out
}


double_merge <- function(df1,df2){
  merge(merge(df1, df2), df2, by.x = "V2", by.y = "V1", suffixes = c("1", "2"))
```

}

the benchmarking becomes :

```
require(rbenchmark)
benchmark(fast_JM(df1,df2),slow_JM(df1,df2),double_merge(df1,df2),
      replications=1,columns=c("test","elapsed","relative"),order="relative")

                    test elapsed relative
1      fast_JM(df1, df2)    0.89  1.00000
2      slow_JM(df1, df2)   12.54 14.08989
3 double_merge(df1, df2)   42.50 47.75281
```

So a speedup of more than 40 times compared to the double merge, and more than 10 times compared to using dataframes.

Comment: @Joris Meys : thanks , i will try it , but i have a question, why did you used -1 at the end here : df2[match(df1$V2,df2$V1),-1]

Comment: @smack : to drop the first column, which is df2$V1. You don't need that in your dataframe. If you have a small dataframe, the method of @Chase might be easier to understand. It will take about 4 times as long on big dataframes though.

Comment: @Joris Meys :  in the new df i got a new column , looks like id or something , but the values are weired (449.105  , 2161.358  ,....) is it normal ??? and how can i remove them??

Comment: @smack : that's not a column, those are the rownames. You can get rid of those by using `rownames(out) <- 1:nrow(out)`

Comment: Can this be adapted for non-unique entries? I have a `df1$a` with a set of values, and a `df2[, c(a, b)]` as a sort of "key" -- `df2$a` contains each unique `df1$a` and a matching `df2$b`. I want to replace each `df1$a` with it's match from `df2$b`. Again, some `df1$a`'s are repeated -- can `match()` work for this (thinking not)?

Comment: @Hendy match() should work actually, as long as df2$a only contains unique values. match(df1$a, df2$a) will give you the row indices of df2 that you can use to cbind with df1.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `merge()` twice to get what you want. By default, `merge` looks for common column names to join. In the second merge, we'll specify the column we want it to merge on:

```
df1 <- data.frame(V1 = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'), V2 = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'))
df2 <- data.frame(V1 = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'), Va = c(12, 15, 321, 54), Vb = c(23, 53, 543, 325))

merge(merge(df1, df2), df2, by.x = "V2", by.y = "V1", suffixes = c("1", "2"))
```

Comment: on larger dataframes, the double call to merge will become very costly. +1 for the suffixes though

Comment: @Joris - good point. I often default to `merge()` since I can mentally draw parallels between `merge()` and the join operators in SQL which I have a lot more experience with than R.

Comment: But merge allows for non-unique entries in `df1`, which may be valuable. The `match()` solution does not appear to do so... so +1 for `merge()` as universal, even if costly.

Answer (score 1):

I think Hadley Wickham's dplyr package has some great tools for combining dataframes. It's a different way to arrive at the same place.

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  V1 = rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 3L),
  V2 = rep.int(LETTERS[1:3], 2L)
)
dfr2 <- data.frame(
  V1 = LETTERS[1:4],
  Va = c(12, 15, 312, 54),
  Vb = c(23, 53, 543, 325)
)

##necessary libraries
library(magrittr, dplyr)
```

Now, using the `left_join()` and `rename()` functions from the `dplyr` package, and the pipe operator from the `magrittr` package, I think you can save a lot of keystrokes.

```
df3 <- df1 %>% #pipe operator (%>%) is from magrittr package
  dplyr::left_join(dfr2, c('V1'="V1")) %>% #merge once
  dplyr::rename(Va1 = Va, Vb1 = Vb) %>%  #rename columns
  dplyr::left_join(dfr2, c('V2'="V1")) %>% #merge on different column
  dplyr::rename(Va2 = Va, Vb2 = Vb) #rename again
```

This can also be done with one merge instead of two, but I like to see what's going on in each step.

```
> print(df3)
  V1 V2 Va1 Vb1 Va2 Vb2
1  A  A  12  23  12  23
2  A  B  12  23  15  53
3  A  C  12  23 312 543
4  B  A  15  53  12  23
5  B  B  15  53  15  53
6  B  C  15  53 312 543
```