# For data.frame in R, pulling data from one data frame based on values from another data frame

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

Sorry if this is really simple, but I've been trying to fin an answer for hours. I have two data frames that contain several columns each, example of similar situation below (actual data frames are very large and cumbersome).

First data frame

```
    "GPS_ID" "Object_ID" "DBH_cm"
     1        19426       15
     2        9456        9
     3        19887       11
     5        18765       4 
     6        9322        7
```

And the second data frame

```
    "Location" "ID"
     block 1    9456
     block 2    18765
     block 2    9322
```

I need to create a new object that has ONLY the ID's in the second data frame matched with their corresponding DBH_cm's from the first data frame. I thought maybe merging would help, but when I tried it, it just added the Location column to the first data frame.

Comment: It's not clear to me what your expected result would look like. I'm pretty sure you can use `merge`, possibly in combination with subsetting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subsetting a data frame based on contents of another data frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452205/subsetting-a-data-frame-based-on-contents-of-another-data-frame)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your final output correctly, the `merge` function should be what you need:

```
> merge(x,y, by.x = "Object_ID", by.y = "ID")
  Object_ID GPS_ID DBH_cm Location
1      9322      6      7  block_3
2      9456      2      9  block_1
3     18765      5      4  block_2
```

You can further edit the new data.frame by removing what columns you don't require.

Comment: Sorry, I feel so dumb, that did the trick. Thanks for your speedy response and patience with my ignorance with R.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `inner_join` from `dplyr`.  If `x` and `y` are the two datasets

```
 library(dplyr)
 colnames(y)[2] <- colnames(x)[2]
 inner_join(x,y, by="Object_ID")
 #  GPS_ID Object_ID DBH_cm Location
 # 1      2      9456      9  block 1
 # 2      5     18765      4  block 2
 # 3      6      9322      7  block 2
```